# Monitor a directory using watchdog and copy it to remote server if the dorectory is modified/deleted/created

Tags: python-3.x

I need a script which monitor the given directory and copy the directory to remote server if there is an update/change in the directory. If destination directory doesn't exist need to create it, But not to delete any directories from remote server. can you help.

I tried the below, But its failing with "its a directory error".

```
import time
import copy
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
class Watcher:
DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/home/xxxxxxx/testwatchdog/testwatch"


def __init__(self):
    self.observer = Observer()


def run(self):
    event_handler = Handler()
    self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, 
    recursive=True)
    self.observer.start()
    try:

       while True:
           time.sleep(5)

    except:
        self.observer.stop()
        print("Error")

    self.observer.join()


  class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

@staticmethod
def on_any_event(event):
    if event.is_directory:
        return None

    elif event.event_type == 'created':
       #Take any action here when a file is first created.
        copy.copy_func()
        print ("Recived created event - %s" % event.src_path)

    elif event.event_type == 'modified':
        # Take any action here when a file is modified.
        print ("Recieved modified event - %s" % event.src_path)
        copy.copy_func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
W = Watcher()
W.run()




import paramiko
import time

def copy_func():

    transport = paramiko.Transport(("xxxxxxx", 22))
    transport.connect(username = "xxxxxx", password = "xxxxxx")
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    sftp.put("/home/xxxxxx/testwatchdog/testwatch/", "/home/xxxxxxx/testwatchdog/testwatch/")
    sftp.close()

  if __name__ == "__main__":

    copy_func()
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried this.